# How do I get QUERY to return the right data?

Tags: google-sheets

So I have this spreadsheet with data in it, there are 29 columns and 54 rows.

On the 2nd sheet I'm trying to find all of the rows that fit a certain criteria.

For some reason, if I include the column X in my query data, the results are completely messed up. The 1st row of the result is just concatenating the first 23 rows together whether they fit the criteria or not. If I only include up to Column W the query is OK and it returns the correct results. But the problem is that I need to get data from Columns A and AB, so I need to include column X in my data range.

In this spreadsheet you can see the data on Sheet1, the query that includes column X on Sheet2, and on Sheet3 I have the same exact query except it only goes up to Column W and you can see the correct results there.

Basically, I need the query to return the value of Column A and Column AB for every row where Column B is marked with an "x".

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXI-LZypI3ID7RSm06nGyzPwYUWzm69rZaxdYqCXATw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filter function to do this , with a literal array :

```
=FILTER({Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!AB:AB},Sheet2!B:B="x")
```

[image]